# External hard drive fail to mount with APFS error "com.apple.DiskManagement.disenter error 49218"

Tags: disk-utility, external-disk, mount, apfs

I can't open my WD external drive after I reboot my mac with Monterey 12.1!

I know that so many people had a similar problem so I followed all those solutions, but they are not working for me. I need to get the documents back so I can`t erase my drive. (ps. don't want to use disk drill).

I found this https://matt.sh/apfs-object-map-free-recovery looks like something might help me but I'm not a coding guy so I'm not able to follow

I tried "mount" in disk utility and I got the (com.apple.DiskManagement.disenter error 49218.)
[image]

When I run first aid in disk utility, I got this:
[image]

I checked the `fsck` , run `ps aux | grep fsck` but only get this

`laijaco           4059   0.0  0.0 34122828    800 s000  S+   11:12PM   0:00.00 grep fsck`

Comment: Just to be sure: do you have a backup of that drive? And when you say "*I followed all those solutions*" can you list them in your question and indicate what didn't work for you? This prevents that someone else will spend time suggesting the same solution, and you becoming frustrated that it does not work. You can [edit] your question to rewrite it with the found/tried/failed attempts.

Comment: This seem to have a serious bug in Monterey. This bug was also reported in https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/695361

Answer (score 2):

WD drives traditionally have very unreliable enclosure hardware, and you may have better luck opening it up, taking the drive out, and putting it in another enclosure. (As a last resort.)

Answer (score -4):

I'm afraid you will need to erase all the data contained in the hdd. Click Erase and you can either click MS-DOS(FAT), APFS or any other format in the Format section and select the scheme right below it. You can click either GUID Partition Map or Master Boot Record. Then Click Erase.
(PS: it works for me when I had it wouldn't mount automatically with a name `disk2s2` in it.)

Comment: The question explicitly states erasing is no option. Even if it was the only option, you should at least explain *why*!