# How to repair Time Machine error Failed to mount with dissenter { DAStatus = 49218; }

Tags: macos, time-machine

All of a sudden, my Time Machine backup, which is on a NAS, would not work any more. In the log, I find

```
2022-05-20 01:41:16.121723+0200  localhost backupd[494]: (TimeMachine) [com.apple.TimeMachine:DiskImages] Found disk5s1 41504653-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
2022-05-20 01:41:16.121746+0200  localhost backupd[494]: (TimeMachine) [com.apple.TimeMachine:Mounting] Attempting to mount APFS volume from disk5s1
2022-05-20 01:41:31.155157+0200  localhost backupd[494]: (TimeMachine) [com.apple.TimeMachine:General] Failed to mount 'disk5s1', dissenter {
    DAStatus = 49218;
}, status: (null)
2022-05-20 01:41:31.720594+0200  localhost backupd[494]: (TimeMachine) [com.apple.TimeMachine:Mounting] Mount dissented, retrying...
```

Time Machine retries a few times, then eventually gives up with

```
2022-05-20 01:03:36.175808+0200  localhost backupd[506]: (TimeMachine) [com.apple.TimeMachine:General] Unmounted '/Volumes/.timemachine/NAS-H-08._smb._tcp.local./01729AE8-7C5E-4CBA-B92B-95CBCDDC2A4E/TimeMachineBackup'
2022-05-20 01:03:36.195282+0200  localhost backupd[506]: (TimeMachine) [com.apple.TimeMachine:General] Backup failed (21: BACKUP_FAILED_DISK_IMAGE_NOT_MOUNTED)
```

Trying to mount the sparsebundle manually with `hdiutil attach` in the terminal, I get

```
hdiutil: attach failed - no mountable filesystems
```

I've loaded the image in Disk Utility and ran First Aid. It didn't succeed with errors like

```
error: cib: ci_free_count (4095) is not valid (0) (ci_addr 0x5980000)
error: cib: ci_free_count (4095) is not valid (0) (ci_addr 0x8360000)
error: cib: ci_free_count (4095) is not valid (1) (ci_addr 0x8378000)
error: cib: ci_free_count (4095) is not valid (5) (ci_addr 0x8390000)
```

Exit code was 8 and error code was -69845. No further explanation or suggestion.

Trying to active the image again returned `com.apple.DiskManagement.disenter-Error 49218`.

What's the problem and is there any way to repair the backup or at least get read access to it?

It's an M1 Macbook Pro on macOS Monterey 12.4 if that matters.

---

Note: [this question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/435383/164512) seems similar, but I think it's different as it refers to an external drive, not an image.

Comment: Is there a `fsck` process running at the same time as the dissenter message is logged?

Comment: @bmike Not sure how I find out. Should `fsck` also run when I try to `hdiutil attach` the image?

Comment: It’s in the question you linked   `ps` or use activity monitor to search. You need to provide more details to attempt to answer a hypothetical `hdiutil`question. We don’t know what you set up, tbh

Comment: @bmike I know how to do it while it's active, but not how to find it in the log afterwards. I'm currently copying the image to my local disk for further investigations, so cannot retry.

Comment: You won’t know after the check finishes. I’d say just run the check later

Comment: There is a huge thread here: https://community.synology.com/enu/forum/1/post/149543?page=1&sort=oldest , but I didn't really find a solution there. Didn't read all of that, though.